# querySelectorAll not displaying all elements in array, Angular material

Tags: javascript, typescript, angular-material, angular9

My array - `viewAllNotes: NodeListOf<Element>` correctly shows multiple items (notes) in the array, but I am not able to return all of the elements in the array, I only see the note at position [1].  There should be two notes from array [0] and [1] displaying, but the array length will also vary in different steps.
(FYI) These notes are suppose to display in Angular 9 Material (mat-vertical-stepper) in a step.  The HTML with the class='all_note' gets injected separately, I do not have access to change it.  (Not able to use Jquery).

Am I missing something?

component.ts...

```
     fims: Array<Element>;
      fimSteps: Array<FimStep>;
      fimStack: Array<FimStep>;
      fimLinks: Array<any>;



   export class FimStep {
              id: string;
              number: string;
              type: 'question' | 'action';
              question: string;
              options: Array<{ target: string, text: string }>;
              linksIds: Array<string>;
              note?: string;
            }

    getFIMSteps() {
        this.fims.forEach(stepElement => {

         const fimStep: FimStep = {
                id: stepElement.id,
                number: number,
                type: 'question',
                question: '',
                options: [],
                linksIds: [],
                note: ''
              };
        let viewAllNotes = stepElement.querySelectorAll('.all_note');

         for (let i = 0; i < viewAllNotes.length; i++) {  
         fimStep.note = viewAllNotes[i] ? viewAllNotes[i].innerHTML : '';
             }

           }
          }
```

component.html...

```
<mat-vertical-stepper #stepper>
<mat-step *ngFor="let step of fimStack">
    <ng-container >
              <div [innerHTML]="step.note"> </div> 
    </ng-container>  
</mat-step>
</mat-vertical-stepper>
```

Comment: first do your loop using a let to keep it blockscoped : for (let i = 0; blabla note the let). I do think however that you could do it the angular way without using querySelector because you know the length of your array

Comment: Thanks, I changed to "let" and edited the description to say the array length will vary.  Let me know if you have any further suggestions to get this working.

Comment: what is the difference between fimStack and fimStep an fimStep get re-assigned in the loop so there will only be one fimStemp.note

Comment: @user3791775, good observation, I added some more code on this.  The fimStack is an array of fimStep objects.  I think if I change the note to a type of array, that may help, but I can't figure out the syntax to put the strings in the note array and then display in the html. (?)